# SAX parser won't ignore non included element attribute in bean definition while unmarshalling

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb, sax

I am trying to unmarshall this XML file :

```
<OpposantParcelles>
        <OpposantParcelle>
            <cin>R92107</cin>
            <opposant>
                <cin>R92107</cin>
                <numMarche>xyz1</numMarche>
                <verrou xsi:nil="true" />
            </opposant>
            <num_marche>xyz1</num_marche>
        </OpposantParcelle>
        <OpposantParcelle>
            <cin>R92107</cin>
            <opposant>
                <cin>R92107</cin>
                <numMarche>xyz1</numMarche>
                <verrou xsi:nil="true" />
            </opposant>
            <num_marche>xyz1</num_marche>
        </OpposantParcelle>
```

with the following code :

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OpposantParcelles.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    OpposantParcelles opposantParcelles = (OpposantParcelles) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("OpposantParcelles.xml"));
System.out.println(opposantParcelles);
```

But I am getting the following exception stating that the prefix `xsi` of attribute `xsi:nil`  of element `verrou` is not bound.

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Douars/OpposantParcelles.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 46; Le préfixe "xsi" de l'attribut "xsi:nil" associé à un type d'élément "verrou" n'est pas lié.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at ma.ancfcc.webIFE.utils.UnmarshallClass.main(UnmarshallClass.java:102)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Douars/OpposantParcelles.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 46; Le préfixe "xsi" de l'attribut "xsi:nil" associé à un type d'élément "verrou" n'est pas lié.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    ... 6 more
```

The problem is that I have not included the element `verrou` in my bean `Opposant`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "opposant")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Opposant {
    private String cin;
    private String numMarche;


    public String getCin() {
        return cin;
    }
    public void setCin(String cin) {
        this.cin = cin;
    }

    public String getNumMarche() {
        return numMarche;
    }
    public void setNumMarche(String numMarche) {
        this.numMarche = numMarche;
    }




}
```

Isn't it the case that the SAX parser should ignore this element ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The SAX parser doesn’t know what you have included in your bean or not. The SAX parser doesn’t even know that there is something like a bean. All it does, it parsing XML files, reporting errors when there are errors. It’s the JAXB `Unmarshaller` which will use the result of parsing the XML file to set up your bean, potentially ignoring XML elements, but when the SAX parser bails out with an error, there is no element to ignore, it will not even get to that point.

Comment: so why is SAX Parser telling me that prefix is not bound, not bound to what ? What's the meaning of this exception ?

Comment: `xsi:nil` is an attribute with a namespace, hence, needs a namespace declaration to be valid XML. The declaration must be present at the same element or one of its ancestors. IIRC, it would look like `xmlns:xsi="namespace uri"`. So the message says `xsi` is not bound to an actual namespace (which usually gets defined by a URI).

Comment: yeah I fixed that and it worked, if you can include your comments in an answer I will accept it

Comment: I just hinted at the problem. If you managed to create a solution based on it, you may write your own answer. I’m fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intercept deserialisation and provide lost namespace information. It can be done using `StreamReaderDelegate` class. See below example:

```
import com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OpposantParcelles.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));

        Object unmarshal = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new XsiTypeReader(xsr));
        System.out.println(unmarshal);

    }
}

class XsiTypeReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {

    public XsiTypeReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
        InputElementStack context = (InputElementStack) super.getNamespaceContext();
        context.addNsBinding("xsi", XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);

        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'InputElementStack' ?

Comment: @mounaim, 'InputElementStack' class comes from `com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack` package. `StreamReaderDelegate` returns it. You need to check what is returned in your case and add new binding. I have included imports to my example code to make it clear which packages and classes are used.